# How to find the Browser rendering time for API in jmeter ,does including retrieve embedded resource gives the overall response time.?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have to do a performance test for application(It has UI) ,It has API requests ,how to find the browser rendering time for APIs , can we do it with retrieve embedded resource. I am quite new to this ,Can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

The only way to measure browser rendering time is using a real browser, if you want to do this along with the existing JMeter performance tests - go for [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler), it provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework so you will be able to kick off a real browser and measure its rendering time (response time of the WebDriver Sampler will be the time from opening the page till the rendering finishes.

If you need the breakdown - consider using [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)